# Cannot install PyCBC using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install PyCBC within a virtual environment in an Anaconda Prompt in Windows 10. I have tried using

```
pip install lalsuite pycbc
```

as suggested in https://pycbc.org/pycbc/latest/html/install.html, and the following error pops:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lalsuite (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lalsuite
```

I have subsequently tried to install it as indicated in https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pycbc :

```
conda install -c conda-forge pycbc
```

and

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pycbc
```

but the packages were not found. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Your question indicates that you are running on Windows 10. There isn't currently a build of lalsuite for Windows. You would either have to install that package (which PyCBC uses) from source (see git.ligo.org) or use a linux-like environment. Options include the linux subystem for windows or a linux virtual machine.

To further clarify, Windows is not a natively supported platform for pycbc / lalsuite, so we haven't built official packages and there hasn't been much (or any) testing in that environment. The conda / pip methods should work in linux or MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have already created a `env`

To install PyCBC within a virtual environment, you can make a fresh clone of the repository.

```
git clone git@github.com/gwastro/pycbc.git
```

Now install the pycbc develeopment environment packages:

```
cd pycbc
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -r companion.txt
python setup.py install
```